# If sender Id exists in other table than show me only the receiver Id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is for members and the second for connecting organizations. Each member has a connection to his organization via organisation_id in the member table.

```
CREATE TABLE member (`organisation_id` int, `user_id` varchar(6));
CREATE TABLE connections (`sender` int,`receiver` int);

INSERT INTO member (`organisation_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
    (10, '1'),
    (30, '2')
;
    
INSERT INTO connections (`sender`,`receiver`) VALUES
    (10, 30),
    (30, 10)
;
```

MY SQL CODE:

```
SELECT sender, receiver FROM (
SELECT *, CASE WHEN sender < receiver THEN CONCAT(sender, receiver) ELSE CONCAT(receiver, sender) END AS fromto FROM connections inner join member on (organisation_id = receiver OR organisation_id = sender) where user_id = '1') AS a GROUP BY fromto
```

A result with the receiver and transmitter ID is currently displayed. But I want that if the Receiver Id belongs to me then it should show me only Sender ID and If the receiver id does not belong to me then he can show it.

Example: `(10, 30)`
Sender ID is `10` and it exists in Member Table with my User Id so it should only show me in that case the Receiver ID `30`

MY SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15c0db/1

Comment: What should the desired result actually *look* like?